Getting error 'Broken pipe (Write failed)' when running MUnit tests and Mule Debugger is not getting started
have been getting below error when running Munit Tests:
INFO 2024-06-14 16:15:51,067 [main] org.mule.munit.remote.coverage.CoverageManager: Calculating application coverage

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at org.mule.munit.remote.notifiers.SocketNotifier.sendMessage(SocketNotifier.java:53)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.notifiers.RunMessageNotifier.sendMessage(RunMessageNotifier.java:159)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.notifiers.RunMessageNotifier.notifyCoverageReport(RunMessageNotifier.java:135)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.listeners.RunEventListenerContainer.lambda$notifyCoverageReport$10(RunEventListenerContainer.java:84)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.listeners.RunEventListenerContainer.notifyCoverageReport(RunEventListenerContainer.java:84)
at org.mule.munit.remote.container.ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.sendCoverageReport(ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.java:417)
at org.mule.munit.remote.container.ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.lambda$runSuites$0(ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.java:156)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
at org.mule.munit.remote.container.ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.runSuites(ContainerSuiteRunDispatcher.java:156)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:85)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:67)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1286)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1231)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1577)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
at org.mule.munit.remote.notifiers.SocketNotifier.sendMessage(SocketNotifier.java:50)
... 11 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at org.mule.munit.remote.notifiers.SocketNotifier.sendMessage(SocketNotifier.java:53)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.notifiers.RunMessageNotifier.sendMessage(RunMessageNotifier.java:159)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.notifiers.RunMessageNotifier.notifyUnexpectedError(RunMessageNotifier.java:145)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.listeners.RunEventListenerContainer.lambda$notifyUnexpectedError$11(RunEventListenerContainer.java:94)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.mule.munit.common.protocol.listeners.RunEventListenerContainer.notifyUnexpectedError(RunEventListenerContainer.java:94)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:96)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:67)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1915)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1576)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
at org.mule.munit.remote.notifiers.SocketNotifier.sendMessage(SocketNotifier.java:50)
... 7 more

I am using Anypoint Studio 7.14.0, using embedded java JDK 8 and trying to run my application with below properties:
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
<mule.maven.plugin.version>3.4.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
<munit.version>2.3.14</munit.version>
</properties>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
<mule.maven.plugin.version>3.4.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
<munit.version>2.3.14</munit.version>
</properties>

I tried removing JDK in my MAC, used other JDK versions version Java 11,13, 17.
Also downloaded and re-installed Anypoint studio many times. Restarted my MAC system. And so on. Still the error is showing up when running Munits.
Could someone please help me getting rid of this error ?
FYI. Strangely Mule Debugger is also not getting started, even after adding break points.

Did it work before? How are executing tests? Can you run the tests from the command line with Maven? Also, you are using older versions of MUnit and Anypoint Studio from 2022. Try with the latest releases. It also could be something in your environment, like an antivirus. And Mule 4.4.0 is only compatible with JDK 8 or 11, don't bother to try with 13, 17, 21, etc.
